# How do I print out this ASCII card in Java, Formatted

Tags: java, user-interface, printing, ascii, blackjack

I am new to java and right now I am making a black-jack game. I want to imitate the real game as much as possible instead of printing out numbers and letters, therefore I made a little ASCII card in wordpad. The problem is, it does not fit inside the "" when I try to print it, and it does not work.

As I said, I am new to Java. Can someone please help me? Thank you.

Here is the card I want to print out:

```
 .-------.  
 | ** ** |  
 |*  *  *|  
 | *   * |  
 |   *   |  
 |   J   |  
 '-------'
```

This is what I tried:

```
String test
 =  ".-------.  
     | ** ** |  
     |*  *  *|  
     | *   * |  
     |   *   |  
     |   J   |  
     '-------'"
```

Comment: If you start with `""` and paste into the string the text you want in your IDE it will translate it into a combination of `\n` and `"` you need. A single String cannot defined across multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) like so:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(".-------.").append(System.lineSeparator());    //System.lineSeparator() gets us the new line character which is used by the underlying OS.
sb.append("| ** ** |").append(System.lineSeparator());
sb.append("|*  *  *|").append(System.lineSeparator());
sb.append("| *   * |").append(System.lineSeparator());
...
```

Then, you print it like so: `System.out.println(sb.toString());`.

Strictly speaking, you could do it through string concatenation:

```
String str = ".-------." + System.lineSeparator() + ...
```

However, concatenating long strings is usually considered bad practice, which is where the `StringBuilder` comes in.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this :

```
    String test
     =   ".-------."+ "\n"+
         "| ** ** |"+ "\n"+
         "|*  *  *|"+ "\n"+ 
         "| *   * |"+ "\n"+ 
         "|   *   |"+ "\n"+ 
         "|   J   |"+ "\n"+ 
         "'-------'";
```